# CSS <style scoped> applies outside of the scope

Tags: html, css

The most simple example of scoped style doesn't work in Chrome (v 25):

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello 1</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Hello 2</h1>
    <style scoped> h1 { color: red; } </style>
</div>
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/RWW8r/2/

Both `h1` become red:

[image]

The scope style should only apply to the second `h1`.

I read that the functionality was implemented in Chrome, why doesn't that work? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. As of this moment, scoped CSS is still an experimental feature which is not supported by any current browser.

However, if you want to play around with it in Chrome you can do the following thing:

- Go to chrome://flags/ in your Chrome browser;
- Find "Enable experimental WebKit features." and click enable
- Restart your browser.
- Try your code. It should work.

Comment: not supported by any current browser is not correct, it is supported by firefox.

Comment: @pilavdzice The answer was valid at the time in February 2013. That's more than a year and a half ago. ;)

Comment: I'll be so glad when Chrome goes live with this feature. I'm enjoying it in Firefox, but I need Chrome to release this feature before I can really go crazy with it. This one of those features that should have been there all along. It's great for modules.

Answer (score 2):

I think when you read that Chrome has implemented it, they meant that it was in the development version, because it certainly isn't in the current release v25.

See the CanIUse site for compatibility charts: http://caniuse.com/style-scoped

Same applies to Firefox; it's only in the current alpha.

Given the pace of development, it'll be in the release version of both these browsers in a relatively short space of time, but the short answer is that it's not there now.

Comment: I tried Chrome Canary and it doesn't work that either. I found a site that mentions that you have to enable it. http://www.impressivewebs.com/scoped-styles-html5/ I'm in agreement with you though, it's way to early to do much with it.

Comment: Aaaand it's gone.

Chrome removed it 37